# Stretch SurfaceView beyond visible bounds of parent?

Tags: android

Does anyone know how I can stretch a surface view beyond the visible bounds of the parent (in this case a LinearLayout)?

I have a 3D video in side by side format that is not supported on non-3D handsets and I'm looking to show only the left half of the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this, you will have to make the parent bigger.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that momentarily